# Thickness of lines, position of box in plot

Tags: r, plot

I am creating a plot with the code below, yet I want to change the following three things and did not succeed so far:

- Obviously, the box is misplaced, how can I place the box such that it is not overlapphing with the plots lines?
- How can I make the lines (the blue and golden of the plot) thicker? Whatever I tried had no effect
- Where can I change the size of the font (axis label, as well as the descriptions in the box and the main label). I know that this is done with par, but not aware where exactly

Thanks

```
blocked <- c(199.80248,  76.67856,  71.21770)
random <- c(193.31283,  99.37955, 104.22490)

g_range <- range(0, blocked, random)


plot(blocked, type="o", col="lightblue", ylim=g_range, 
     axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)


axis(1, at=1:3, lab=c("Pretest","Posttest", "Retention"))


axis(2, las=1, at=40*0:g_range[2])


box()


lines(random, type="o", pch=22, lty=2, col="gold")

title(main="Radialer Fehler der geblockten und variablen Gruppen", col.main="black", font.main=2)


title(xlab="Test", col="black")
title(ylab="radialer Fehler (mm)", col="black")


legend(1.1, g_range[2], c("geblockt","variabel"), cex=0.7, 
       col=c("lightblue","gold"), pch=2:3, lty=2:3);
```

Comment: I don't see any indication in your question that you have put sufficient effort into consulting the documentation.

Comment: I did, I just did not list everything I did, plus, its not that R documentation is really good..quite to the contrary

Comment: Did you try http://shinyapps.stat.ubc.ca/r-graph-catalog/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify graphical parameters either golbally with `par` or at each call to a plot function, ie `plot`, `lines`...

To get a list of all graphical parameters, you can simply type `par()`.

Concerning your problem, you can make the lines thicker with graphical parameter `lwd`, either typing first `par(lwd = 1.5)` (or lower/greater, play with it to see the result) or at each call :

```
plot(blocked, type="o", col="lightblue", ylim=g_range, axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE, lwd = 1.5)
lines(random, type="o", pch=22, lty=2, col="gold", lwd = 1.5)
```

Graphical parameter for the size of the font is `cex`. You can also change the place of the legend using the parameter `topright`,`topleft`etc. :

```
legend("topleft",...)
```